# Is there a function in Beautiful soup that allows you to find the index of a specific <p> tag

Tags: python, html, indexing, beautifulsoup, tags

I would like to get the index of the `<p>` tag of the first object in the percussion list. How would one go about doing that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


data = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instruments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Guitars are string instruments </p>
    <p> Saxophones are woodwind instruments </p>
    <p> Drums are percussion instruments </p>
    <p> Pianos are percussion instruments</p>
</body>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
pattern = '(?=.*percussion).*'
percussion = soup.findAll(string=re.compile(pattern))
print(percussion[0].parent.name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.index` method. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Instruments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Guitars are string instruments </p>
    <p> Saxophones are woodwind instruments </p>
    <p> Drums are percussion instruments </p>
    <p> Pianos are percussion instruments</p>
</body>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

percussion_p = soup.find("p", text=lambda t: "percussion" in t)
all_p = soup.find_all("p")

print('Index of <p> with text "percussion" is:', all_p.index(percussion_p))
```

Prints (0-indexed):

```
Index of <p> with text "percussion" is: 2
```